# Issue with Fuzzy Output - Gaussian

Tags: gaussian, fuzzy-search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O9vv.png)I'm experiencing an issue with my fuzzy output. In the 'view rules' section, the returned value doesn't seem to correspond to the output area.

I have a fuzzy logic system in which I'm defining rules and using Gaussian membership functions. When I try to visualize the rules and the resulting output in the 'view rules' section, the value I'm getting doesn't match what I expect in terms of the output area.

As shown in the figure, Rule 8 appears to be the best match for the output. However, the obtained value is not within the output area specified in Rule 8.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with fuzzy logic systems and Gaussian membership functions? Any advice or suggestions on how to rectify this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!